# How can I use a pre-assigned variable in dplyr::filter?

Tags: r, dplyr

When I assign `expt` as below, I get a tibble of dim 175, 81:

```
expt <- 5
mydata <- loaded_data %>% filter(expt == expt) %>%
  select(leaf.TN.pc | starts_with("air_")) %>%
  drop_na(leaf.TN.pc)
```

This is not what I want. Instead if I assign `expt` inline, as:

```
mydata <- loaded_data %>% filter(expt == expt) %>%
```

I get what I want, which is only obs from experiment 5, dim = 79, 81.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did was comparing `expt` column with itself which was always true.
Below the solution that will work for either one chosen value (`expt_chosen <- 1`) or multiple values (`expt_chosen <- c(1, 3)`). Just use `%in%` operator.

```r
library(tidyverse)

expt_chosen <- c(1, 3)

dframe <- data.frame(name = letters[1:5], expt = 1:5)
dframe
#>   name expt
#> 1    a    1
#> 2    b    2
#> 3    c    3
#> 4    d    4
#> 5    e    5

dframe %>% filter(expt %in% expt_chosen)
#>   name expt
#> 1    a    1
#> 2    c    3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>